# Cython Extern C++ Function

Tags: cython

I'm trying to extern a c++ function to cython. Here is my code (all files are in the same directory)

function.cpp

```
int cfunc(int x){
    return x;
}
```

wrapper.pyx

```
cdef extern from "function.cpp":
    cpdef int cfunc(int)

def pyfunc(int x):
    return cfunc(x)
```

setup.py

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

source = ['function.cpp', 'wrapper.pyx']
ext = [Extension('lib', source, language='c++')]
setup(ext_modules=cythonize(ext))
```

When I run `python setup.py build_ext --inplace` it gives the following error

```
/home/hyunix/anaconda3/envs/c-playground/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/function.o: in function `cfunc(int)':
function.cpp:(.text._Z5cfunci+0x0): multiple definition of `cfunc(int)'; build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/wrapper.o:wrapper.cpp:(.text._Z5cfunci+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command '/home/hyunix/anaconda3/envs/c-playground/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-c++' failed with exit status 1
```

However if I remove `language='c++'` from setup.py it works fine. Why does this happen?

I'm using:

- Python 3.7.9
- Cython 0.29.21
- Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 0):

Well, when you use cpdef int cfunc(int), you're explicitly creating a new C function, and a new python function. If you want to refer to cfunc() as it's externally defined in function.cpp, your signature should be

```
cdef extern from "function.cpp":
    int cfunc(int)
```

So, when you compile with the language='c++' flag, Cython is giving you an appropriate error. However, when you remove the language flag, Cython needs to reason based on compiler directives whether you're asking for a .c or a .cpp, and it defaults to .c. You should notice that your wrapper is being compiled to .c instead of .cpp when the language argument is removed. In this C compilation, Cython does not recognize the signature in the .cpp, but it does recognize the cpdef. So, no error, but you're getting an empty cfunc function, as opposed to the one defined in cpp.

Comment: Hi @Aitrean thankyou for answering. I tried compiling without the language flag, and it does compile into a (.c) wrapper like you said, however it actually recognizes the function defined in the (.cpp) file and run as expected.  I also tried removing the cpdef on the extern part and still receive the same error, am I missing something?